# PHP text parsing by using list, foreach and explode

Tags: php, arrays

i have a text file as list.txt. the contents of list.txt are as below:

```
user1:site1.com
user2:site2.com
user3:site3.com
user4:site4.com
```

i used the following code :

```
$a=file('list.txt');
foreach ($a as $final) {
list($user, $site) = explode(":", $a);
echo ($user." is the user of ".$site);
}
```

I want the output to show:

```
user1 is the user of site1.com
user2 is the user of site2.com
user3 is the user of site3.com
user4 is the user of site4.com
```

can anybody please solve my problem.I am a beginner in php.and I have problems in array function.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. What is the problem?

Comment: Try changing the $a in the explode to $final

Comment: This needs basic debugging first, `var_dump` is your friend.

Comment: What exactly IS your problem? It helps, when you actually formulate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exploding the `wrong variable`

```
list($user, $site) = explode(":", $a);
```

With

```
list($user, $site) = explode(":", $final);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($user, $site) = explode(":", $final);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can spot, that might cause something strange behavior is in your third line where you should use `$final` instead of `$a`. `$a` still holds the complete content of your file while `$final` holds the current line assigned by the `foreach`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

this will work as you need,

```
<?php 
$a=file('list.txt');
foreach ($a as $final) {
$user=explode(':',$final);
echo ($user[0]." is the user of ".$user[1]).'<br/>';
 }
?>
```